# SQL query time series data to find trend counts for user activity

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Using Postgres 8.4. I have a table of user activity that looks like kinda like this:

```
userid    |  timestamp           |  action
---------------------------------------------
0001      |  11/11/2015 9:00:02  |  X
0001      |  11/11/2015 9:00:22  |  Y
0002      |  11/11/2015 9:01:02  |  Z
0002      |  11/11/2015 9:03:02  |  W 
0003      |  11/11/2015 9:04:02  |  X
0004      |  11/11/2015 9:05:02  |  Y
```

What I need to do is find counts of the number of users that performed a series of actions  **X** and then **Y**
or **X** and then **Y** and then **Z** with a count of how many users made it to the next step.

So I have as input an ordered set of actions that and I want a count of how many users got through those actions (1st step: action 1 , 2nd step: action 2, 3rd step)

I'm trying to get a results like

```
step | action |  count
=======================
 1    |  X     | 100       <---- 100 users did X
 2    |  Y     |  55       <-----55 did X and then Y (45 dropped away)
 3    |  Z     |  12       <-----12 did X and then Y and then Z (43 more dropped)
```

As you can see the the count is always decreasing: 100 users did X, of those that did X 55 did Y and of those 12 did Z.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you are using a Postgres version that is no longer maintained (=supported). You should really upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Well actually I'm using redshift which is based on a fork of 8.4

Comment: Redshift is even older than that if I'm not mistaken. I think it's fork of 8.0

Comment: No its not. Its an Amazon petabyte scale DB as a service that was an acquisition. The original company forked their product off of 8.4 and built a highly parallel, column based db.... but none of that is really relevant. I'm tied to functionality that was available in 8.4

Comment: Is there a limit on how far apart the actions can be? And what if they repeat for one user (x,y,x,y,z)?

Comment: How is the order x -> y -> z defined? Implicitly by the timestamp? Or is this a given order?

Comment: the order is given @a_horse_with_no_name, so that the user did X followed by Y (potentially with other actions in between) followed by Z (again, potentially with other actions in between)

Comment: @JakubKania there is no limit on how far apart with respect to date. Repitition is irrelevant so long as it was done. Your example of (x,y,x,y,z) is a valid sequence that should qualify it for counting

Comment: FYI this type of report is commonly referred to as a "funnel". Eg sales funnel, conversion funnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution will be probably to use `LEFT JOIN` to join the table with itself:

```
WITH actions(action) AS(
  VALUES ('X'),('Y'),('Z'))
SELECT d.action
       ,Count(DISTINCT a.userid)
FROM table1 as a
  LEFT JOIN table1 AS b
    ON a.userid = b.userid AND b.action = 'Y' AND a.timestamp < b.timestamp
  LEFT JOIN table1 AS c
    ON a.userid = c.userid AND c.action = 'Z' AND b.timestamp < c.timestamp
  JOIN actions AS d
    ON d.action IN (a.action, b.action, c.action)
WHERE a.action = 'X'
GROUP BY d.action
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2451a/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one rather brute force approach.  Use `listagg()` to create the sequences, and then look for them:

```
select p.pattern, count(t.actions)
from (select 'X' as pattern union all select 'XY' union all SELECT 'XYZ'
     ) p left join
     (select userid, listagg(action, '') within group (order by timestamp) actions
      from table t
      group by userid
     ) t 
     on t.actions like concat('%', p.pattern, '%')
group by p.pattern;
```

Comment: Neat idea. In Postgres `listagg()` would be `string_agg(action, '' order by timestamp)`  but I don't know about Amazon RDS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Amazon RDS went with the Oracle syntax:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html.

Comment: cool idea. I think it can be improved by using arrays instead of concated strings

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be a better way using some other SQL features.

But a simple one would be doing something like the query I paste below.

That one would get you the users that did X-Y-Z, the X-Y should be easily done by modifying this query.

```
select count(distinct(userid)) from user_activity u1
where action = 'Z' 
and exists
  (select userid from user_activity u2
   where u2.userid = u1.userid
   and u2.date < u1.date
   and u2.action = 'Y'
   and exists (
     select userid from user_activity u3
     where u3.userid = u2.userid
     and u3.date < u2.date
     and u3.action = 'X'
     )
   )
```

Comment: So this would only get me the count of users that did all three events. What I need is the breakdown showing the users that did the first thing, went on do the second thing and went on to do the 3rd thing. This way you can see the number of users that dropped off (or didnt complete) each action. I'll edit my question to make this clearer

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: @xtrakBandit: if you first run a query counting the distinct users that did 'X', you get the first number you want, then you modify the query I pasted to calculate the number that did 'X-Y' and you get the second number you want, then you use the query I provided and get the third number you want. If it's just 3 actions you have, running those 3 separate queries might be a viable option.

Comment: You're right @eugenioy it's a viable option but still not ideal for purposes. I think there is a way (possibly using window functions) to achieve this in one query - if I come up with a solution I'll post it.